# Problem setting attribute in JS with popover data-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, hover, popover

I am trying to display content when hovering over an icon.
When I hardcode it in my HTML it works fine.
But when I try to render the same thing through javascript, nothing happens on hover.

So this works when written in HTML directly:

```
<i id="iconid"
class="ki flaticon2-information icon-lg ml-3 text-dark"
data-container="body" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-html="true"
data-content="hello"i>
```

This does not work

```
    <!--html-->
    <i id="iconid"
class="ki flaticon2-information icon-lg ml-3 text-dark"
data-container="body" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-html="true"
i>

<!--javascript-->
document.getElementById("iconid").setAttribute("data-content", "hello");
```

When I inspect the rendered code, everthing seems exactly the same in both cases, but in 2nd case nothing happens on hover.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bootstrap, you might want to call popover event manually after manipulating element by JS.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

I think issue is, by the time you call your JS manipulation, bootstrap already finished binding events for the elements. So it got left behind.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to be the issue in deed. Now it works, but only when I click the icon, not when I hover over it. And I have to click it again to make the 'hello' dissapear. How can I add the hover feature?

Comment: @jeff3546, check bootstrap documentation. popover accepts parameters as argument. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#usage